# Flutter how to get "content of list" using a "list of index"?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
List a = [3,5,7]
List b = [apple, banana, cake, coke, car, train, dog, paper]

output: coke, train, paper
```

Any function in Dart can achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  List<int> a = [3, 5, 7];
  List<String> b = [
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'cake',
    'coke',
    'car',
    'train',
    'dog',
    'paper'
  ];

  List newList = a.map((e) => b[e]).toList();

  print(newList);
```

More info on map

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/Iterable/map.html